# input date - minYear, maxYear and monthNames doesn't work CAKEPHP 3.4.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use CakePHP date input, but I have a problem with it, when I put a year in "minYear" or "maxYear" or when a set an array of months in "monthNames" it doesn't work, I don't know why, when I open the browser it shows the months in number format and the year interval is not applied. I am using the latest CakePHP version (3.4.2).

```
<?= $this->Form->date('data_ini', [
            'minYear' => 2000,
            'maxYear' => 2000,
            'monthNames' => ['01'=>'Janeiro','02'=>'Fevereiro','03'=>'Março','04'=>'Abril','05'=>'Maio','06'=>'Junho','07'=>'Julho','08'=>'Agosto','09'=>'Setembro','10'=>'Outubro','11'=>'Novembro','12'=>'Dezembro']
           ]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the `maxnYear` key to `maxYear` and it will works.

Comment: thanks, but it was not the only problem, it continue doesn't work